# Good resources (book or otherwise) to learn/study basic Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying basic Combinatorics for a college course and my professor is awful (and that is being generous).

Therefore I'm looking for good resources to learn basic Combinatorics so that I can prepare for his exams and ace the course.

Thanks for any help

Comment: knuth's concrete mathematics is the first thing that comes to mind. It's a good book and quite  an entertaining read.

Comment: Related can be tried.  Good Book On Combinatorics https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outline for high school combinatorics class?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122663/outline-for-high-school-combinatorics-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMO there are two great references at two different levels. The first is [Brualdi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131001191). This book is awesome. It is super clear, super straightfoward, and very readable by yourself.

The second is much more advanced, but even better! It is [Aigner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642072534)'s GTM on the subject. This book is fairly advanced, but rarely have I seen such a beautiful exposition of any mathematical subject. His proofs are impressively elegant, and his exercises are very interesting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Brualdi is decent but so error-ridden that it's annoying to read.  That was 15 years ago, however... maybe he's finally cleaned it up in the latest editions.

Comment: @Fixee there have been many many editions.