# Book recommendation Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

This semester I will be taking a masters degree course on combinatorics and I am looking for a book that covers the material of the lecture and some more advanced stuff so I can gain some deeper insights. More specifically the topics will be the theory of species, polya theory (i.e., enumeration of objects with symmetries), partially ordered sets and asymptotic enumeration. Additionally I am also interested in graph theory so if the book also has some chapters about that it would be nice too. There is also a [script](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emfulmek/scripts/KOMBI/skriptum.pdf) for the lecture with a more detailed list of contents if that helps. It would be awsome if it is written not too dense, i.e. not in a theorem-proof kind of fashion like hartshorne's algebraic geometry for example, but rather has a lot of examples and explanations in it and possibly also covers the prerequisites or at least refers to them in some way. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The scilabus has some interesting references you probably want to check, all of them are classics. **Flagolet-Sedgewick** *analytic combinatorics* contains a lot of example and is quite nice to read.

Comment: Mo145@ Have you checked out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781790/book-recommendation-olympiad-combinatorics-book?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46087/good-textbooks-on-combinatorics-for-self-study?noredirect=1&lq=1