# Combinatorics Books

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

I am studying combinatorics in my class right now and am using Combinatorics by Van Lint and Wilson. I was wondering if any of you guys had any recommendation on a supplementary book for topics like generating functions, enumerative combinatorics in general and extremal combinatorics? I am looking especially for a book with a lot of exercises so that I can practice solving problems.

Thanks!

Comment: For enumerative combinatorics you could do a lot worse than Miklós Bóna, *A Walk Through Combinatorics*; it’s considerably more elementary than Van Lint & Wilson, but it has lots of exercises, many with full solutions. For something more at the level of Van Lint & Wilson there’s Richard Stanley’s *Enumerative Combinatorics* (two vols.), but its’ a bit much for a *supplementary* text. The second edition of Herbert S. Wilf’s *generatingfunctionology* is freely available as a PDF here; it’s a superb introduction to generating functions and has lots of problems and solutions.

Comment: Peter Cameron's *Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms* is also a good choice.

Comment: Thaks for the book suggestions guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics)

Answer (score 1):

Van Lint and Wilson is really great, but you may also like Enumerative Combinatorics Volumes I and II by Richard Stanley. Generatingfunctionology by Wilf is second to none for generating functions specifically.