# Reference request for Combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I'm looking for a book with variety of combinatorics exercises specially enumerative problems.

I have found some lecture notes but they were not coherent.

What do you advise?

Comment: Make it coherent by adding a missing information. Can you give us an example, where you got stuck?

Comment: I found some minor pdf for some topics such as double counting, generating function , etc. But I need a reference with wide variety of topics not some specified

Comment: There are of course many such references, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics). But whether they are coherent for you or not, depends also on how you work with it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend Laslo Lovasz [Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821842625) named "Combinatorial Problems and Exercises".

It contains all you want.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I supposed to. I believe that it's best exercise book in combinatorics.

Comment: Yes, I think it is very good. It was also the answer of minasteris [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics).

Answer (score 0):

You could also benefit by checking out the following Video lecture series ( It also contains problem sets , at the appropriate stages) on NPTEL . 
http://nptel.ac.in/courses/106108051/

This is basically an introductory undergrad level course on Combinatorics given at one of the premier Engineering institutions of India.