# Combinatorics books that tackle and intermediate level

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I have been studying enumerative combinatorics using the book by George Martin: *Counting: the art of enumerative combinatorics*. I would like to continue learning the subject, but the problem is that I have found with two types of books: either they're too problem-approached (Chen and Koh: *Principles and techniques in combinatorics*), or rather too technical (Stanley: *Enumerative combinatorics vol. 1*). I am looking for an applied approach (but if it is mathematically oriented it is nice also). It would be nice if they have **correct** answers (I have been dissapointed by such good books like Charalambos: *Enumerative combinatorics*, or Tucker: *Applied combinatorics* which contain a bunch of errata).

EDIT:

Found this: [Intermediate Text in Combinatorics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/intermediate-text-in-combinatorics?rq=1)

Comment: Book will be bound to contain errors. That's not a reason not to read them.

Comment: True, but in learning combinatorics it is essential to do a lot of problems. If there are errors in the answers, this can only confuse to someone who is new in the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Miklos Bona, $\textit{A Walk Through Combinatorics}$.

Comment: I wanted to recommend this book.