# A basic Combinatorics Book

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, self-learning

So, this is my problem...I have completed my boards and among all others, I have a great weakness in combinatorics. So this means I can utilize my free time now to address this problem. I think it is because of the fact that  my understanding of the basics is not correct.

So, I am asking which book should I consult to have a better understanding of the basics in combinatorics. I would like to have a book which is rigorous and builds up the theory from the beginning(possibly with also a little bit of history). I mainly though aim to have a stronghold on the topics of permutations and combinations, the inclusion-exclusion principle, the pigeonhole principle, colouring proofs(things like covering chessboards) and other things that an interested student ought to know in high school. The book need not have difficult problems, for I can find difficult problems.

One such book(in Number Theory), I have read is Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton(the first few chapters and bits of later chapters). I telling you about this book so that I can possibly be clear of what kind of book I am looking for.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Richard-Brualdi/dp/0136020402

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good resources (book or otherwise) to learn/study basic Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6245/good-resources-book-or-otherwise-to-learn-study-basic-combinatorics)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a high school-level book, you might consider *The Mathematics of Choice: Or, How to Count Without Counting* by Ivan Niven.  I don't think it covers coverings of chessboards, so far as I can recall, but it covers all the other topics in your list.  You can buy the book direct from the Mathematical Association of America: http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/mathematics-of-choice-or-how-to-count-without-counting

This book was my first introduction to combinatorics, way back when I was in high school, and I remember it fondly.

Answer (score 2):

You may go through the list in this [mathoverflow page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29137/good-combinatorics-textbooks-for-teaching-undergraduates). I think that covers almost all the good books out there!

My advice would be to learn programming if you do not know yet. 
There are many good and free computer algebra systems, make use of it.

This would serve many advantages - you can be confident with your answers if 
it matches with the computer output, you can get insights, perform monte-carlo simulations for approximate answers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most books nowadays cover standard materials that probably won't help you that much. I am also weak in "counting". So I look for **Intro to Combinatorics** written by the Arts of Problem Solving. This one of a kind book also teaches you the math for olympiad and that is what you like to know.So advice to you is go to their site and order the book.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Bogart's ["Combinatorics through Guided Discovery"](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/ComboNoteswHints11-06-04.pdf), it is tailored to self-study.

Adding to the previous answers, do look around for lecture notes on the web. There are many available, much awful but you'll find some gems too. The more interesting ones will probably have loads of old exams and homework nearby.

Comment: can you pinpoint me the gem lecture notes you're referring to?

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy, it was just a general comment. In any case, you'll have to find some you understand/like anyway