# Combinatorics for Complete Beginner

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations, combinations, book-recommendation

I am studying in high school and I find permutation and combination very difficult to follow. I currently use [A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817642889) which is a bit difficult for me to understand. please suggest some good books that clearly explains the basic principle pretty well.

Comment: @ven you probably want to [merge your account](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get back the ownership of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A basic Combinatorics Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813478/a-basic-combinatorics-book)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to start with ["Introduction to Counting and Probability"](http://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intro-counting) and ["Intermediate Counting and Probability"](http://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intermediate-counting) which are excellent books for math contests such as the AMC10, AMC12, AIME and the USAMO.

A few other good books would be,

1) Combinatorics: A Guided Tour *by David R. Mazur*

2) A Course in Combinatorics *by Lint and Wilson* (For further continuation of combinatorics)

Comment: The book by Lint and Wilson is not for beginners!

Comment: You are supposed to do that book after A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates