# References for books of Combinatorics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a high school student who will go to a university this year.I want a Combinatorics book that'll actually clear my basic principles of Permutations and Combination (and would also give me insights of proof).The book also must have a good problem set related to these principles. Basically, I want a book which will "COMPLETELY" clear all my basic principles of combinatorics.
I thought of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics book

Comment: Stanley's book, although excellent, is specialised. By this I mean you would need some guidance to see the 'real world' applications of the  concepts in that book. If you are a starting undergrad, I recommend the book 'Counting: The
Art of Enumerative Combinatorics' by George E. Martin. It has a lot of problems and solutions at the back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorics for Complete Beginner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520390/combinatorics-for-complete-beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this text says "for Computer Science", but the explanations are detailed, thorough, and insightful. See https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring17/mcs.pdf

EDIT: For a more detailed treatment of permutations and combinations, see "Introductory Combinatorics" by Brauldi (you can find PDFs via Google).

For derangements, see Chapter 5 of "Enumerative Combinatorics" by Charalambos Charalambides (again, you can find PDFs on Google). I really like his treatment of the topic, as it is much more accessible than Stanley's.

Comment: I actually need a book about permutation and combination which have the topics ( e.g. Inclusion-Exclusion ; Pigeon-Hole ; Derangement; Multinomial theorem and its good examples to solve)

Comment: The one I provided has many examples and explanations of inclusion-exclusion and pigeonhole, but I can link you another reference that adds more detail on derangement and multinomial shortly.

Comment: Link it please.

Comment: Please see the edit.