# Suggestions for a book on olympiad-level combinatorics assuming minimal backgrounds

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book particularly for olympiad combinatorics which only assumes high school level knowledge.
Please drop me some suggestions.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/store

Comment: "Problem Solving Methods in Combinatorics: An Approach to Olympiad Problems" by Pablo Soberon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good resources (book or otherwise) to learn/study basic Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6245/good-resources-book-or-otherwise-to-learn-study-basic-combinatorics)

Comment: Thanks for the comments I find Pablo the best option for me right now.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [AoPS store](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/all-products). There are many books available there. I do not know what kind of book you are specifically looking for, but I'd recommend [Intermediate Counting & Probability](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/book/intermediate-counting).

Answer (score 6):

102 Combinatorial Problems by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng, free PDF here - https://rainymathboy.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/102-combinatorial-problems.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1981002)

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace This comment "From Review" and its upvotes are strange. It is not a link-only answer, and it already follows the format you suggest. The essential part of the answer is the recommendation of the book *102 Combinatorial Problems* by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng, and the link is provided for reference.

Comment: @JamesMartin Unfortunately this seems to be a common response across stack exchange to a new user, regardless of the answer's quality. A few times I've posted perfectly fine answers only for someone to say otherwise, and I wonder if they even read it (if anything my first reaction would be to wonder if the PDF is "really" free, but other than that I don't see what's wrong with this answer).

Comment: @Thierry this link to the book is a top result on google when you look up the book

Comment: Thanks a lot, after seeing the level of problems, I am truly overwhelmed. I think it would be suitable for me to use this book after doing the book by Pablo, as this one has only problems.